# Atmel Studio 7: USART interrupt handler provided by ASF library works once only in case of encountering infinite loop in main()?

Tags: c++, c, atmelstudio

Currently, I am using **usart_read_buffer_job** function provided by ASF library. I placed this function inside the while(1) loop as below:

```
int main()
{
  Some pieces of code for initialization;
  while(1)
  {
    usart_read_buffer_job();
    while(1) // The second infinite loop
    {
      Some other pieces of code;
    }
  }
}
```

It works perfectly well for the first interrupt handler call. However, after returning from the handler, I was no longer able to call the interrupt handler. The program kept running within the second infinite loop and was not able to execute usart_read_buffer_job() again. It was probably the cause of the handler 's malfunction.

In this case, my purpose is to jump into the USART interrupt handler regardless of the number of infinite loops being executed in main(). Of course, by not using ASF, the issue could be solved by manually set the handler but I still wonder how this issue could be solved by other functions provided by ASF.

Looking forward to getting the response from the community soon.
Thank you,

Comment: The pseudo-code above is somewhat confusing in draining the buffer only once during initialization. I don't know the library but typically receive interrupts will continue until the buffer is full and then mask themselves until space is freed up, with your program being responsible for extracting data at regular intervals though with buffering relaxing the deadline. To handle _infinite_ stalls I would guess that you'd process data directly from the interrupt receive callbacks instead, with all of the races that entails. Or is all you require is an immediate buffer-overflow notification?

Comment: please post the contents of: `usart_read_buffer_job();` and the contents of the `usart` interrupt handler.  As it is, the posted information is not sufficient unless we also have the same `Atmel Studio 7`.   Most of us will not have that specific development system, so you need to provide us with the details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for very quick response.

The code which I am working on is confidentials. Hence, I could only share the ASF library functions with you and explain briefly how they work.

In the ASF, typically, we have two functions for handling the interrupt, namely **usart_read_buffer_job** and **usart_read_job**

Before using these two functions, the handler calls are defined by the two functions:

**usart_register_callback**: Registers a callback function, which is implemented by the user.

**usart_enable_callback**: The callback function will be called from the interrupt handler when the conditions for the callback type are met.

And these two functions above are placed in the initialization code as shown in the question.

Then, depending on the design purpose, handlers are called whenever a character or a group of characters are received via UART peripherals using usart_read_buffer_job/usart_read_job respectively.

**usart_read_buffer_job**: Sets up the driver to read from the USART to a given buffer. If registered and enabled, a callback function will be called.

**usart_read_job**: Sets up the driver to read data from the USART module to the data pointer given. If registered and enabled, a callback will be called when the receiving is completed.

You could find more details about these functions on http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/samd21/html/group__asfdoc__sam0__sercom__usart__group.html

In this case, assumming that the main program stalls due to some unexpected infinite loops, the handlers should still work at anytime after receiving command invoked from the UART peripherals and do some important tasks to solve out the problems, for example.

Hope that this explanation makes my previous question clearer. And, hope to get response from all of you soon.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not put an infinite loop inside an infinite loop!!.
If you find yourself doing this, this indicates a probable design flow. Please revise your design.
(Let's call it the first rule)

Second, you seem to use event driven I/O (rather than polling) by registering a handler/callback.
Here is a second rule, you never call a handler yourself.
You register a callback function (handler) to be called when the event occurs.

If you are doing the initialization and configuration correctly, the code should work following this scheme:

```
void initialization()
{
  /*Device and other initialization*/
  ...
  usart_register_callback(...); /*Register usart_read_callback() here*/
  usart_enable_callback(...);
}

int main()
{
  initialization();
  while(1)
  {
      /*Some other pieces of code*/
  }
}

void usart_read_callback(...)
{
  usart_write_buffer_job(...); /*Read data into your read data buffer*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually, the second infinite loop is created intentionally to simulate errors. For example, my program is only able to continue its process with essential data received from the external world, such as acknowledgement from RF module. The case may be translated in code like `while(!received_ack_data()) {nop;}`. The program stalls due to wait for acknowlegement and interrupt handler is needed to find out what is going on within the program. For second suggestion, handler does not seem to be called without executing the usart_read_buffer_job/usart_read_job in main().

Answer (score 0):

`usart_read_buffer_job()` will only invoke the callback *one* time, so after the callback has been dealt with, you must invoke `usart_read_buffer_job()` again (perhaps at the end of the callback if the processing is finished).

Only one infinite loop can run unless you have some kind of separate tasks (such as in FreeRTOS), each with their own loop.